# Special characters on insert to postgres db with psql

Tags: php, postgresql, character-encoding, psql

I try to add special char "†" with psql to varchar field, but no success. From php application it works (php user as iso8859-1).

setting for db are:

```
encoding = LATIN1
collation = fi_FI
character type = fi_FI
client both UTF8 & LATIN1 (on commandline PGCLIENTENCODING=LATIN1 or PGCLIENTENCODING=UTF8)
```

selecting from table
shows when client is UTF8

```
locationx \u0086
```

How to add value from psql to database? Neither below are not working.

```
update tablex set field1 = 'locationY' || '†'
update tablex set field1 = 'locationY' || U&'\86'
```

giving error messages.

```
ERROR:  character with byte sequence 0xe2 0x80 0xa0 in encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in encoding "LATIN1"
ERROR:  invalid Unicode escape value at or near "\86' "
```

If I view the data entered by my PHP application, the bytes are `\x6c6f636174696f6e5986`, but when I enter the data with `psql`, the bytes are `\x6c6f636174696f6e59e280a0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work from either PHP or `psql`, because the character `†` does not exist in LATIN-1 encoding. You just cannot store it in the database.

Let me explain what is going on.

- If your client encoding is `LATIN1` and you enter in `psql`:

  ```
  INSERT INTO ... VALUES ('locationY†');
  ```

  gets stored successfully, because your terminal is set to UTF-8. So the `†` you type is actually three bytes: `\xE280A0`, which are interpreted and stored as three single-byte characters.
- If your client encoding is `UTF8` and you enter in `psql`:

  The same insert will cause an error, because the three bytes that are entered when you type `†` will correctly be interpreted as the dagger character, and there will be an error when PostgreSQL tries to convert the character to `LATIN`:

  ```
  ERROR:  character with byte sequence 0xe2 0x80 0xa0 in encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in encoding "LATIN1"
  ```
- With PHP, your client encoding is probably set to `LATIN1`, and the PHP program actually uses the WINDOWS-1252 encoding.

  Then `†` is represented by the single byte `\x86`. That is interpreted by PostgreSQL in the `LATIN1` encoding, where it means something entirely different, namely the “start of selected area” control character `U+0086`.

  Now when your PHP program reads that character back, everything **seems** to work fine, but the database actually stores a different character than you intend.

  You will notice that as soon as you try to select the value by any other means, e.g. on your `psql` console. There the value will be rendered as

  ```
  locationY\u0086
  ```

Here is a solution how to get things working:

- Create a new database with `UTF8` encoding.
- Dump the old database with

  ```
  pg_dump -F p -E LATIN1 dbname
  ```
- Manually edit the dump and change the line

  ```
  SET client_encoding = 'LATIN1';
  ```

  to

  ```
  SET client_encoding = 'WIN1252';
  ```
- Load the dump into the new database with `psql`.
- change the `client_encoding` of your PHP application to `WIN1252` and start using the new database.